# If $(x+1)^2-2x>2(x+1)+2,$ then $x$ cannot equal which one of the following?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am preparing to GRE Quant and I ran into one problem which seems to me bit false.

If $(x+1)^2-2x>2(x+1)+2,$ then $x$ cannot equal which one of the following?

(A) -5

(B) -3

(C) 0

(D) 3

(E) 5

The above inequality is equivalent to $x^2-2x-3>0$ and the set of solutions is $(-\infty,-1)\cup(3,+\infty)$.

Immediately we get that $x$ cannot equal $0$ and $3$.
So the answers are (C) and (D).
However in official GRE Guide the answer is (C). Am I false? I rechecked every step in my solution and did not find any mistakes.

Please help

Comment: Nope, you're correct - you can plug in $3$ to check. Probably a typo in the book.

Comment: you are right. It cans be $C$ or $D$. If you change $>$ by $\ge$ then you get just $C$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: one can write your inequality in the form $$(x+1)^2-2(x+1)>2(x+1)$$ can you finish?
this is equivalent to $$(x+1)^2-4(x+1)>0$$ and this $$(x+1)(x-3)>0$$ and your term $$x^2-2x-3=(x+1)(x-3)>0$$ your solution is right.

Comment: I did not get what you mean. Could you continue your approach? Do you suppose that my sokution is false?